# solve docker error: curl gives : (28) error port 443: Couldn't connect to server

Tags: windows, docker, curl, https

Trying to build windows image with docker and download a file with CURL.

Dockerfile is as below. I get:

`curl: (28) Failed to connect to aka.ms port 443 after 21099 ms: Couldn't connect to server`

Dockerfile:

```
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

# Use the latest Windows Server Core 2022 image.
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

# Use the latest Windows Server Core 2022 image.
#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

RUN `
    # Download the Build Tools bootstrapper.
    curl -SL --output vs_buildtools.exe https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe --connect-timeout 30`
    #ipconfig /all `
    `
    # Install Build Tools with the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools workload, excluding workloads and components with known issues.
    && (start /w vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
        --installPath "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools" `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10240 `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10586 `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393 `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK `
        || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0) `
    `
    # Cleanup
    && del /q vs_buildtools.exe

# Define the entry point for the docker container.
# This entry point starts the developer command prompt and launches the PowerShell shell.
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat", "&&", "powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

tried adding 8.8.8.8 as DNS on the host, but the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the DNS IPs inside Docker. To do that you have 2 main solutions

The first is to use the `DOCKER_OPTS` variable which allows the user to set options in the Docker configuration.
In your case you can set the environmental variable:

```
DOCKER_OPTS = "--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"
```

The other solution is to run the container with the --dns option which sets the DNS inside the container:

```
docker run --rm --dns=8.8.8.8 <image-name>
```

Take a look of the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/#dns-services).

Another workaround is to srt the DNS from the Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf && \    
    command_depending_on_dns_resolution
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried the first, set that as environment variable but I have the same error.
The second is not an option for me as I need this when building an image, not when running an image.

Comment: I updated my answer with another workaround you can set directly from the Dockerfile

Comment: thank you @Alez , but both the base image and host are windows. Also, I don't think its the name resolution that fails. I replaced the link to [http://34.223.124.45/favicon.ico](http://34.223.124.45/favicon.ico) and the error is the same.